# how to get connection between android device and xmpp server?

Tags: android, client-server, xmpp

Gibberbot I have been trying to get on Gibberbot from now some time but I am getting only one error. "Unable to sign into the XMPP service. Please try again later. (Detail: Cannot connect to your server. Please check your connection.)" 
https://github.com/guardianproject/gibberbot

Comment: have you add permission INTERNET on your project?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using asmack library to connect from Android client to the OpenFire XMPP server. Guess, it can be used for any other server, too. This asmack library provides a set of classes to connect, create chats, see roster etc etc. Although this asmack project, as I understand, is not being actively developed recently, it still worked for me fine. Asmack stands for Smack for Android, I guess.